# How to update DB records to active/inactive for inputs inside loop in codeigniter

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I am trying to update specific row in tables using select options tag .But it is updating last inserted row only and not the specificed.
I need solution.

controller:

```
public function user_status()
{     
    $this->load->model('customize_model');
    $data = array("user_status" => $this->input->post('status'),
     "user_id" => $this->input->post('user_id'));
    $data1['user'] = $this->customize_model->update_status($data); 
    $this->load->view('custom/user',$data1);
}
```

Model:

```
public function update_status($data)
{
    $user_id = $this->input->post('user_id');
    $this->db->set($data);
    $this->db->where('user_id',$user_id);
    return $this->db->update('user',$data);     
}
```

My View:

```
                <?php
                 foreach($user->result() as $row)
                 {
                ?>
                    <tr>
                        <input type="hidden" class="form-control" 
                         value="<?php echo $row->user_id; ?>" 
                         name="user_id" />
                        <td><?php echo $row->user_id; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row->user_status; ?></td>
                    <td>
                            <select class="form-control" name="status"  
                             id="user_status">
                                <option value="Active">Active</option>
                                <option 
                                value="Inactive">Inactive</option>
                            </select>
                    
                        </td>
                        <td>
                        <button class="btn btn-primary" name="submit" 
                         type="submit" value="<?php echo $row->user_id;? 
                         >"> Update<?php echo $row->user_id;?></button>   
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                <?php 
                    }
                ?>
```

Comment: how this can be posted to controller using jquery ajax by adding extra input checkbox coumn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is the same name="user_id" is looped in your view along with other name attributes. So the last value is sent to the controller.

In View:
Create two inputfields

```
<input type="hidden" name="global_userId" id="global_userId" />            
<input type="hidden" name="global_status" id="global_status" />
```

Try setting the name and id as

```
name="status-<?php echo $row->user_id; ?>" id="status-<?php echo $row->user_id; ?>"
```

for all name attributes in loop.
and make the button type button rather than submit and make it call function onclick.
like

```
onClick="submitForm(<?php echo $row->user_id; ?>)"
```

and create the Jquery function to update the input field and submit the form:

```
function submitForm(userId){
  $('#global_userId').val(userId);
  var status = $('#status-'+userId).val();
  $('#global_status').val(status);   
  $('#formId').submit();                                            
}
```

In controller and model accept the 'global_userId' and 'global_status' for the values.

```
$user_id = $this->input->post('global_userId');
```